# TensorFlow tensor shape error midway through training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a music genre classification problem. My training data consists of `.wav` files organized into different subfolders.

When I run the script to train my model, everything is fine for the first few epochs, but then I get an error:

```
Epoch 11/20
236/280 [========================>.....] - ETA: 22s - loss: 0.5967 - accuracy: 0.8497Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ashka\Desktop\spring 23\Apply AI\music-classification\Jupyter\mel2-ash-FULL-production.py", line 217, in <module>
    model.fit(
  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf-2\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf-2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 7209, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__ExpandDims_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Tried to expand dim index 2 for tensor with 1 dimensions. [Op:ExpandDims]
```

This is very strage behavior, as I would imagine shape issues being detected much earlier in the code, such as in the following snippet:

```py
print("Abnormal shapes:")
for item_tuple in train_ds:
    shape = item_tuple[0].shape
    if (shape != (BATCH_SIZE, MEL_DETAIL, 1163, 1)):
        print(shape)
```

which doesn't print anything:

```
Abnormal shapes:
```

What's stranger is that there is no specific epoch during which this happens. If I run the same script twice, it will happen at a different point. During the immediate next round after this, the problem occured during epoch 5. Keep in mind that my random seed is predefined and it doesn't change.

Here's my script:

```py
import keras
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # unused in python script
import os
import numpy as np
import librosa  # library for audio analysis
import sys

print(tf.__version__)
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

print("Executing eagerly?", tf.executing_eagerly())

print("GPU:", tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

# declare global variables
TRAIN_SET_DIR = os.path.join('..', 'halved')
RANDOM_SEED = 42
VALIDATION_RATE = 0.1
FREQ_CAP = 7000
SAMPLING_RATE = 22050
SAMPLING_LENGTH = 27  # seconds
MEL_DETAIL = 64
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 20

# create array to store all the training song paths
song_paths = []
unique_genre_nums = os.listdir(TRAIN_SET_DIR)
song_genre_nums = []

# loop over each music genre
for genre_num in unique_genre_nums:

    # in each music genre, add the paths of all the music to the array
    for song_path in os.listdir(os.path.join(TRAIN_SET_DIR, genre_num)):
        song_paths.append(os.path.join(TRAIN_SET_DIR, genre_num, song_path))
        song_genre_nums.append(int(genre_num))

# convert both of these to np arrays for efficiency
song_paths = np.array(song_paths)
song_genre_nums = np.array(song_genre_nums)

# suffle both arrays with the same shuffle seed
np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)
np.random.shuffle(song_paths)
np.random.shuffle(song_genre_nums)

# split both into training and testing sets
num_songs = len(song_genre_nums)
num_validation = int(num_songs * VALIDATION_RATE)

validation_genres = song_genre_nums[-num_validation:]
validation_paths = song_paths[-num_validation:]

training_genres = song_genre_nums[: -num_validation]
training_paths = song_paths[: -num_validation]

print("number of validations")
print(len(validation_genres))
print('number of trainings')
print(len(training_paths))

# ------- this should roughly be the number of songs that we're using -------
# number of validations
# 1990
# number of trainings
# 17919


def create_dataset(audio_paths, audio_classes):

    # create zip dataset
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(
        (
            tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(audio_paths),
            tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(audio_classes)
        )
    ).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    # map each path to a spectrogram
    # contains the mel from all sources' first [SAMPLING_LENGTH] seconds.
    ds = ds.map(
        lambda x, y: (tf.py_function(make_mel, [x], tf.float32), y),
        num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    ).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    # print(ds)

    return ds

# get path, read audio data, pass it into next func to get mel, then return it
# this will be used in map (look above)


def make_mel(path):
    # the first x seconds of the track are imported
    path = path.numpy().decode('ascii')

    audio_data, _ = librosa.load(
        path, sr=SAMPLING_RATE, duration=SAMPLING_LENGTH
    )
    mel = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(
        y=audio_data, sr=SAMPLING_RATE, n_mels=MEL_DETAIL, fmax=FREQ_CAP
    )

    # EXPERIMENTAL: expand dimensions so you have 4
    mel = tf.expand_dims(mel, axis=2)

    return mel


# convert path and class arrays to dataset...
train_ds = create_dataset(training_paths, training_genres)
valid_ds = create_dataset(validation_paths, validation_genres)

# DEBUG: print the dimensions of all tensors different from (64, 64, 1163, 1)
# doesn't print anything...

print("Abnormal shapes:")
for item_tuple in train_ds:
    shape = item_tuple[0].shape
    if (shape != (BATCH_SIZE, MEL_DETAIL, 1163, 1)):
        print(shape)

# model -----------------------------


class CNN(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, **kwargs):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.conv = layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size)
        self.normalization = layers.ReLU()
        self.pooling = layers.MaxPool2D()

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            'filters': self.filters,
            'kernel_size': self.kernel_size,
        })
        return config

    def call(self, input):
        # print("=====================\n",input)
        x = self.conv(input)
        x = self.normalization(x)
        x = self.pooling(x)
        return x


model = keras.Sequential()

# convolutional layers
model.add(CNN(32, 3))
model.add(CNN(64, 3))
model.add(CNN(128, 3))

# flatten
model.add(layers.Flatten())

# dense layers
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
# model.add(layers.Dense(19, activation = 'softmax'))
model.add(layers.Dense(19, activation='linear'))

# compile
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit
model.fit(
    train_ds,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)

# evaluate
model.evaluate(valid_ds, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

# save model
model.save('models/mel2-ash-FULL.keras')
```

I thought this might be a problem with my memory, so I reduced the batch size slowly, until I reached 1. But I still got the same behavior.

I did, however, manage to reduce the frequency of the occurance by doing one of these two things: reducing the size of the daset size to a half / quarter, or reducing my epochs. But these aren't real solutions as they directly affect the model's performance.

Is there a way to fix this issue without affecting the final model?

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by using `mel = tf.expand_dims(mel, axis=-1)` instead of `mel = tf.expand_dims(mel, axis=2)`. This simply adds an axis to the tensor regardless of its shape. I'm still curious as to why the original line wouldn't work. More specifically, why the error is raised in a random epoch instead of at the beginning.